# ¿cómo puedo traer los datos que me responde mi servicio soap?

Tags: php, soap

Lo que sucede es que me dieron un endpoint y necesito traer los datos de ese endpoint pero con lo que tengo me sale el siguiente error

> no operations defined in the WSDL document!

Traté de modificar de varias formas en las que envió la data y no he podido. Agradezco de antemano su colaboración. Aquí les dejo mi client.php:

```
<?php
include_once('lib/soap/nusoap.php');

$documento=22129614;

$wsdl = "http://siga-pro-svc.azurewebsites.net/Servicios/Implementaciones/ProcesoCRMService.svc";
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl,true);
$client->soap_env="soapenv";
$namespaces=[
    'soapenv' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope',
    'tem' => 'http://tempuri.org/',
    'apl' => 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Aplicacion.ContextoPrincipal.Mensajes.ModuloIntegracion.CRM'
];

$param = array('NumeroDocumento'=>$documento,'TipoDocumento'=>'c');
$datos = array('params' =>$param,"namespaces"=>$namespaces);
$client->namespaces=$datos['namespaces'];
$resultado = $client->call('obtenerDatosVehiculoPropietarioPeticion',  $param);

print_r($$client->responsive);

if ($client->fault) {
    echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
    print_r($resultado);
    echo '</pre>';
} else {
        $err = $client->getError();
        if ($err) {
            echo '<h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';    
        } else {
            echo '<h2>resultado</h2><pre>';
            print_r($resultado);
            echo '</pre>';
        }
}
```

Comment: El valor de la variable  `wdsl` no debería apuntar al archivo `wsdl` del webservice?..... o sea, que ternime con `?wsdl`

Comment: ya se o coloque pero sigue saliendo el mismo error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La URL que debes cargar en tu variable **$wsdl** es esta:

http://siga-pro-svc.azurewebsites.net/Servicios/Implementaciones/ProcesoCRMService.svc?wsdl

Ahí está ubicado el WSDL que describe el servicio y las operaciones que quieres consumir, lo puedes verificar pinchando en el enlace y te mostrará el XML crudo.

Tu código debería quedar así:

```
$wsdl = "http://siga-pro-svc.azurewebsites.net/Servicios/Implementaciones/ProcesoCRMService.svc?wsdl";
```

y además cambiar la linea del call, porque la operación no es la que estas usando, debería quedar así:

```
$resultado = $client->call('obtenerDatosVehiculoPropietario',  $param);
```

Saludos!